# Why is `ArrayBuffer.from("string")` not working in this case

Tags: scala

In this code when compiled with sbt 1.3.8, with `scalaVersion := "2.12.10"` in the `build.sbt`, I get an error on the `.from(s)` that says:

```
[error] /home.../Hello.scala:37:26: value from is not a member of object scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
[error]     val ab = ArrayBuffer.from(s)
                                 ^
```

source code fragment:

```scala
package example

import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

object Test {
  // yes this is a contrived example
  def abFromStr(s:String) : ArrayBuffer[Char] = {
    val ab = ArrayBuffer.from(s)
    return ab
  }
}
```

but when I do this, it works:

```scala
scala> val ab = ArrayBuffer.from("test")
ab: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Char] = ArrayBuffer(t, e, s, t)
```

My `scala` REPL is version 2.13.1, so I'm guessing that the "companion object" for ArrayBuffer that implements `from` is not in version 2.12.10 - but I can't find anything to confirm that in the documentation. What am I doing wrong?

[*2nd day scala noob*]

Comment: On [`2.12` **ArrayBuffer**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.10/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer$.html) doesn't have any `from` method, which it does on [`2.13`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer$.html).

Comment: as I figured... it would be handy if they had the first version where the feature appeared in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected and Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez pointed out in the comment above, the `.from` method on the `ArrayBuffer` is not available in 2.12.10. I would be nice if the docs indicated in which version a function / object / etc. first appeared.

Comment: Rather than looking up the origin version of this or that method/object/etc., you could, instead, just stick to the [ScalaDocs pages](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.12.10/index.html) for the Scala version you're working with. (Note the link's full path.)

Comment: That makes sense. It happens in my case, as a new user, I installed Scala per the instructions, and got 2.13.1 REPL, and then installed sbt and created a new project from the template, and got compiler version 2.12.10. Now when working in the project and REPL side by side, I ended up with two different experiences. The same is possible in other environments - like Haskell for example. In F# / .NET the docs typically show the first version where a class / function is available. Just saying that since there's a version footgun possibility, this would be useful information in the docs.